# Turning a list into a dictionary adding headers

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'd like to turn the following list in a dictionary:

```
detail_flights = ['17:20 – 19:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '17:20 – 19:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n11:35 – 13:05\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '17:20 – 19:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n12:05 – 13:45\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '17:20 – 19:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n20:15 – 21:55\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m]
```

I'd like to add the following headers. Each element of the list needs to have its own header.

```
detail_headers = ['departure_time', 'departure_airport', 'to_delete', 'arrival_airport', 'type_flight', 'duration']
```

This is my code:

```
num = len(detail_flights)
num_detail_headers = detail_headers*num

from itertools import zip_longest
new_detail_flights = detail_flights[0].split("\n") 

dictionary = dict(zip(num_detail_headers , new_detail_flights ))
print(dictionary)
```

And the following is my output. I obtain the dictionary only for the first element of the list and I can't understand why.

```
{'departure_time': '6:20 – 8:00', 'departure_airport': 'BCN Barcellona-El Prat', 'to_delete': '‐', 'arrival_airport': 'BGY Bergamo Orio al Serio', 'type_flight': 'diretto', 'duration': '1h 40m'}
```

Comment: I think because you are forming a single dict but with duplicate keys.....maybe you wanted a list of dicts or tuple of dicts instead of a single dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line

```
new_detail_flights = detail_flights[0].split("\n")
```

only take the first element.

To take all element, you can do :

```
from itertools import zip_longest


detail_flights = ['17:20 – 19:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m',
                  '17:20 – 19:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n11:35 – 13:05\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m',
                  '17:20 – 19:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n12:05 – 13:45\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m',
                  '17:20 – 19:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n20:15 – 21:55\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
detail_headers = ['departure_time', 'departure_airport', 'to_delete', 'arrival_airport', 'type_flight', 'duration']


new_detail_flights = []
for flight in detail_flights:
    new_detail_flights.append(dict(zip(detail_headers , flight.split("\n"))))

print(new_detail_flights)
```

witch output :

```
[
    {
        'departure_time': '17:20 – 19:00',
        'departure_airport': 'MXP Aeroporto Malpensa',
        'to_delete': '‐',
        'arrival_airport': 'BCN Barcellona-El Prat',
        'type_flight': 'diretto',
        'duration': '1h 40m'
    }, 
    {
        'departure_time': '17:20 – 19:00',
        'departure_airport': 'MXP Aeroporto Malpensa',
        'to_delete': '‐',
        'arrival_airport': 'BCN Barcellona-El Prat',
        'type_flight': 'diretto',
        'duration': '1h 40m'
    },
    {
        'departure_time': '17:20 – 19:00',
        'departure_airport': 'MXP Aeroporto Malpensa',
        'to_delete': '‐',
        'arrival_airport': 'BCN Barcellona-El Prat',
        'type_flight': 'diretto',
        'duration': '1h 40m'
    },
    {
        'departure_time': '17:20 – 19:00',
        'departure_airport': 'MXP Aeroporto Malpensa',
        'to_delete': '‐',
        'arrival_airport': 'BCN Barcellona-El Prat',
        'type_flight': 'diretto',
        'duration': '1h 40m'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

> I obtain the dictionary only for the first element of the list and I can't understand why.

Here you only take the first element from the list:

```
new_detail_flights = detail_flights[0].split("\n")
```

I think this is what you want:

```
dictionaries = [
    dict(zip(detail_headers, detail_flight.split("\n"))
    for detail_flight in detail_flights
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not just a single dictionary, but a list of dictionaries. So replace this

```
dictionary = dict(zip(num_detail_headers , new_detail_flights))  # This will just zip the first set of 6 headers, thus the 2nd set would be ignored.
print(dictionary)
```

To

```
flights_count = len(new_detail_flights) // len(detail_headers)
dictionaries = []
for index in range(flights_count):
    start = index * len(detail_headers)
    end = start + len(detail_headers)
    dictionaries.append(dict(zip(num_detail_headers, new_detail_flights[start:end])))  # During the first iteration, this will zip the first set of 6 headers. Upon second iteration, the second set of 6 headers. And so on.
print(dictionaries)
```

Output (pretty printed)

```
[
    {'departure_time': '17:20 – 19:00', 'departure_airport': 'MXP Aeroporto Malpensa', 'to_delete': '‐', 'arrival_airport': 'BCN Barcellona-El Prat', 'type_flight': 'diretto', 'duration': '1h 40m'},
    {'departure_time': '6:20 – 8:00', 'departure_airport': 'BCN Barcellona-El Prat', 'to_delete': '‐', 'arrival_airport': 'BGY Bergamo Orio al Serio', 'type_flight': 'diretto', 'duration': '1h 40m'}
]
```

Comment: Please share the reason of the vote down. I maybe able to improve it based on the reason.